# Including jars in vert.x vertice

Tags: java, jar, debian, vertices, vert.x

I am building a simple rest api, in which I need to use a third party jar.

My program is currently a single .java-file, and I have put the .jar-file in the same path as the .java-file I'm running as a vertice.

How do I go about including the .jar-file in my vertice? I am running the server using debian linux, and I'm new to both linux, java and vert.x.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was ust a matter of setting the CLASSPATH to point towards the .jar-files, not vert.x-related.